# What is the context between texture features and image anomaly detection?

Tags: neural-networks, feature-engineering, anomaly-detection

I have been looking into deep image anomaly detection, more specifically the feature extraction component, for quite a while now. (My focus is on deep learning)

I have encountered various papers about texture features like texture classification etc. in my research. Since I am quite new to deep learning I can not really comprehend how these texture features contribute to an anomaly detection framework.

My dataset I would like to evaluate an anomaly detection framework on consist of various objects like screws, bottles and hazelnuts. If I had a dataset that would consist of only texture images I would understand that texture features would be enough for anomaly detection.

I do know that each object has a texture, but are texture features enough to detect anomalies in these objects? What kind of features need to be extracted to do so?

Thank you in advance, for any kind of answer!

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what are you asking for. A texture can be a property of an object, just like its shape, orientation, and relative position to other objects. If you can extract features describing a texture, why should treating them be any different from any other features?

Comment: I do not quite get how "important" texture features are for anomaly detection on objects. And what other kind of features are needed for good anomaly detection.

Comment: How important a particular feature is for a given task depends highly on the particular data in use. It is best answered by running some experiments on the data in question. Hard to answer anything meaningful "in general".